# WPF / C# Display of Acrobat Toolbar

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, axacropdf

I'm creating a WPF application that has viewing of PFDs built into it.  I use WindowsFormsHost method to view the PDF:

`<WindowsFormsHost x:Name="PDFViwer"/>`

`var pdfViwer = new AdobePDFViewer(@"E:\temp\test\testFile1C.pdf");`

`this.PDFViwer.Child = pdfViwer;`

I've noticed that when I view some files (such as electronic version of books), the Acrobat Toolbar will display automatically, such as this:

[image]

However, some other files that are.. let's say created from a Word Document or sent to print to PDF, will display the document in Read Mode, which brings up a menu bar at the bottom if you hover towards that area, such as this:

[image]

I like the second better than the first; however, due to the fact that some users might not know that hovering towards the bottom will display those options, I want to be able to force those options to display.

If I click the Acrobat symbol on the popup menu that has a caption of Show Acrobat Toolbar, it'll go into the mode where the Toolbar will display at the top... but once again, the user has to know of the popup menu existence in the Read Mode.

Is there a way to force the Toolbar to display by default or a way to make a custom button force mode switch?

Adobe doesn't have the greatest developer documentation in the world... why can't everyone be like Oracle.  They'll provide a list of methods, but don't provide a clear list of possible parameters or a very clear description of those methods.. So I've been playing with `this.axAcroPDF1` methods and one of them does something halfway to what I'm trying to accomplish: `this.axAcroPDF1.setShowToolBar(true)`.  However, what that does is displays the Adobe Reader Toolbar at the top of the document while still in Read Mode.  So, I have a toolbar on top and the dynamic toolbar on bottom, which is a bit messy in my opinion.  I can't figure out how to switch modes... there are more methods, but I can't find the list of available enumeration parameters for them.

I don't believe how ridiculously hard it is to find information on Adobe products if you're a developer...  I guess I was spoiled by Oracle's incredible documentation of Java.  Anyways, I've even read through this "lovely" document, and I still can't figure it out: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to customize current view as described in [link](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf)

Comment: Yeah, I've already looked through that file.  Half of it for HTML opening.  I can get thumbnails or bookmarks to open in addition to the top toolbar, but I can't disable the bottom dynamic toolbar.  If only I could find a way to change view mode from Read Mode to the regular one.  Half of the people that will be using this application have limited computer knowledge and throwing extra flashy stuff at them will scare and confuse them.